# Unable to retrieve FCM token for firebase cloud for Android/IOS app Ionic

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an Ionic Android/IOS app which includes push notifications from firebase cloud messaging. However, I am having problems with retrieving the token.

I have tried a couple of variations but they all lead to errors.

```
...
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';

@Injectable()
export class FcmNotificationProvider {
  constructor(
    public firebaseNative : Firebase,
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    public afMessaging : AngularFireMessaging,
    private platform: Platform,
    private fcm: FCM
  ) {}

getToken() {

this.fcm.getToken
      .subscribe(
        (token) => { alert('We got a token', token); },
        (error) => { alert(error); },  
      );
}}

// gives an error
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

I also tried  using `AngularFireMessaging` and got a different error when running on my android device.

```
    this.afMessaging.getToken
      .subscribe(
        (token) => { alert('We got a token', token); },
        (error) => { alert(error); },  
      );
```

When I install and run the apk on my device i get the following error:  `"This browser doesnt support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).`

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: That last error message seems pretty clear to me.  What browser and what version of that browser are you using?

Comment: The last error message occurs when trying to run the app in android not in a browser.

Comment: Are you using ionic v3? if so what is your ionic-native/firebase version?

Comment: "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.2.0", 
"firebase": "^5.8.2",
    "ionic": "^4.10.3",